# getting data from ConfigObject

Tags: groovy

How to get data from this confstruction:

```
sth {
 [
    firstname="me"
    second="sfdg"
 ]
 [
    adress="adfhajkfdh"
 ]
}
```

I used ConfigObject but when I get from it keySet it gives me whole list(firstname, secondname,adress) bu I have to separete it. Is any way to get data from only one tab e.g. only "firstname" and "secondname".

Comment: The code you're trying might help? Also, are you sure that's the config you're using?  I can't see how that would work at all (or even parse)

Comment: Previous version of this script doesn't contain '[', ']' characters. This values was displayed on the screen. But my boss wants to see this valueas in few columns, so I must implements something which help me to do it. values in first [... ] blok will be dislpayed in first collumn. Second [] blok - second column. I wanted to do it that way: sth { col_1{...} col_2{....}}. But for him it doesn't look well.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you used to have config like:

```
sth {
  firstname="me" 
  second="sfdg"
  adress="adfhajkfdh"
}
```

but you now want to structure that into columns?

One way this could be done is by structuring each column into a separate property like so:

```
sth {
  column1 {
    firstname="me"
    second="sfdg"
  }
  column2 {
    adress="adfhajkfdh"
  }
}
```

Or, you could declare another columns property which constains a list of columns (each of which is a list of properties that you want in each column), ie:

```
sth {
  firstname="me" 
  second="sfdg"
  adress="adfhajkfdh"
  columns = [ column1:[ 'firstname', 'second' ], column2:[ 'address' ] ]
}
```

Personally, I prefer the second approach as it should still work with your old code, you don't need to iterate the ConfigObject structure to get all the properties, and properties could be in multiple columns (if this becomes a future requirement)

Comment: Thanks! When my boss saw this answers he stoped pushing me to do it without inner {} blocks :)